# Google api limits for platforms (DFP)

Tags: google-api, google-dfp

I'm not sure where to read about the API request limit for a Google platform such as DFP.

I want to know if the limits are on a per platform basis, or a per google API console account basis? Because there may be several API accounts under 
a single platform

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to [their support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/quota|sort:relevance/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/wIhegP08DV0/DMtE3hW4AwAJ),

> The API will give a [QuotaError](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201608/ForecastService.QuotaError) if the number of requests exceeds the limit. It is recommended to implement a back off before retrying the request. If you have DFP Small business, then it is recommended to limit requests 2 per second, if you have a Premium account, limit 8 requests per second.

For any additional information you could refer their,

- [Online Documentation](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/start)
- [Ask for help in their Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api)

Hope that helps. Cheers